# Can legendary firearms spawn?

Tags: dead-island

In Dead Island, there are named legendary weapons, la crème da la crème, which are an upper class of orange rarity (non-named legendaries). Wikis document named legendary firearms, but I have never seen one spawn nor have I seen anyone with one in my community where modding is not possible. Is it possible for named legendary firearms to spawn legitimately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they cannot spawn legitimately.

How can I prove it? I can't. I will merely point to the fact that there has never been a verifiable claim that one was found legitimately.

Answer (score -2):

Most of them are taken from metal chest or from fallen zombies. Here the 23 legendary weapons: (Direct quotes from the [wiki](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Legendary_Weapon))

> Assassins greed: metal chests in the city of Moresby, and occasionally in metal chests in the Laboratory area, as well as looted from a fallen zombie.
>
> Ban: metal chests or on dead enemies
>
> Banisher: metal chests or obtained from a fallen zombie.
>
> Bloodletter: bought from Wayne at the Paradise Survival Camp
>
> Blunt Speaker: metal chests or as a random drop
>
> Boucer's Pal: can be found in the hotel
>
> Bushmaster: random drops or weapon chests
>
> Crowd Pleasure: random drops and in metal chests.
>
> Defender of the Motherland: rare drop that can be found on dead enemies or in metal chests
>
> Dragon Knife: bought from Wayne at the Paradise Survival Camp
>
> Eviscerator:
>           The Eviscerator is not found in any precise location. It is a random drop from zombies across the Banoi Island and has a small chance to be looted from metal chests.
>          There have been reports of players acquiring it as early as during the quest "Light My Fire" in the Resort area and all the way to the Jungle chapters.
>          It has been reported to have been found in the beach area lodged in a walkers head next to a corpse under a yellow and white umbrella
>
> Gabriel's Sledgehammer:  completing her quest "Bury the Dead" (Level when collecting reward make weapons's stats vary)
>
> Home Run: dead enemies or be found in metal chests with small chance of spawning in random location
>
> Italian plumber: locked chest
>
> M.C: dead enemies or in metal chests
>
> Master Chef: metal chests and occasionally looted from a fallen zombie.
>
> McCall:  dead enemies or in metal chests with small chance of spawning in random location
>
> Pick of Destiny: quest "Fallen Angel"
>
> Tijuana machete:  quest "Where is my pineapple?" (Level when collecting reward make weapons's stats vary)
>
> Two Parter: dead enemies or in metal chests with small chance of spawning in random location
>
> Viking of the south: metal chests throughout the Banoi Island or obtained from a fallen zombie.
>
> Zed's Demise: quest "The Butcher of Banoi", (Level when collecting reward make weapons's stats vary)

So Two Parter, McCall and Home Run can be found by spawn with very small chance, at random location, but also by metal chest and killing zombie/enemies

Comment: Could you add more information about it, looks like your answer is so sparced ...

Comment: @Michel: Edited